# Rewrite rule on multiple variables using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how can I rewrite `www.site.com?lang=lv&type=1&mode=2` into `www.site.com/lv/1/2` using Apache mod_rewrite options.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you actually want to rewrite `/lv/1/2` to `?lang=lv&type=1&mode=2` (I see no reason to do the opposite) and that no other rewrites are active, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ?lang=$1&type=$2&mode=$3 [L]
```

Also; you'd be better off replacing those magic numbers with more useful information if you want to include them in your URI.

**Edit:** If it really is the opposite you'd like to do, see the answer by Matt S.

Comment: Yes, I ment the opposite :P Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basic rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.site.com/?lang=(.+?)&type=(\d+?)&mode=(\d+?) http://www.site.com/$1/$2/$3 [L,R=permanent]
```

**Edit:** Changed rewrite flags to force a permanent redirect

Comment: That does seem to be working:The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Do you have a page that responds to `site.com/lv/1/2`? Are you using a framework of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the URI path and query separately. If the parameters appear in that very same order, you can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([^&]+)&type=([^&]+)&mode=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]
```

Otherwise you will need to put them in the right order before using this rule or take each parameter at a time.

Comment: None of these is working any way, is there something else I need to change in Apache configuration or other?

Comment: @werd: Are you using the obligatory `RewriteEngine on`? And where do you want to use that rule?

Comment: Yes I am using it, I am using it on site index. In root directory I have index.php and .htaccess files

Comment: @werd: Are you using any other rules that can conflict with this one?

Comment: @werd: And the URL path is always just `/` and there are always these three URL parameters all having a value?