# htaccess file rules

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess

I have such rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^art_(.*).htm$ art_item.php?id=$1
```

And link like this: `art_1.html => art_item.php?id=1`

Now I want to add sublink which looks like: `art_1/5.html => art_item.php?id=1&id2=5`

```
RewriteRule ^art_(.*)/(.*).htm$ art_item.php?id=$1&id=$2
```

I tried that, but server throws 404 error. What's wrong?

Comment: Don't you want `RewriteRule ^art_(.*)/(.*).html$ art_item.php?id=$1&id2=$2`? What does `var_dump($_GET);` (assuming you're using PHP) show?

Comment: @daniel sorry, a little mistake in typing. Still the same problem.

Comment: Quick suggestion: if you're going to be matching numeric values, match them explicitly with ^art_(\d+)/(\d+).htm$  ... also, using '.*' implies 'greedy' matching which can be empty, I think what you really want is '.+?'. As written the first rule matches 'arg_Zhtm'! ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181615/rewrite-rule-on-multiple-variables-using-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: Are you sure it's not an htm/html mix-up?

Comment: html vs. htm can be solved using '\.html?' which indicates an explicit period followed by 'htm' and an optional 'l'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to be careful about the order of the rules.

wrong order:

```
RewriteRule ^art_(.*)\.html$ art_item.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^art_(.*)/(.*)\.html$ art_item.php?id=$1&id2=$2
```

correct order:

```
RewriteRule ^art_(.*)/(.*)\.html$ art_item.php?id=$1&id2=$2
RewriteRule ^art_(.*)\.html$ art_item.php?id=$1
```

This is because `(.*)` also matches `(.*)/(.*)`, since the `/` is *any character matched by `.`*.

Second: there is a difference between `.htm` and `.html`, so either be careful or just use `\.html?`, which matches both.

Comment: Good point, but it looks like you forgot to switch the rules in the "correct" order?

Answer (score 1):

The following should cover it assuming `id` is numeric (it's best to be as exact as possible):

```
RewriteRule ^art_(\d+)\.htm$ art_item.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^art_(\d+)/(\d+)\.htm$ art_item.php?id=$1&id2=$2
```

**Note:** `id2` for the second capture